# Payfort integration in wooCommerce | Showing error on checkout, and order pending for 3d Secure response

Tags: woocommerce, payfort

I am integrating payfort in wooCommerce site, I have installed the payfort plugin, and configured according to my payfort test account settings.
Now on checkout its showing error

> There are some issues with the items in your cart. Please go back to the cart page and resolve these issues before checking out.

I tried to check order history on wooCommerce which showing transaction status pending, then I checked on payfort test account logs, and I found the response for this transaction was sent with response_message `3d secure check requested`.

Now I wonder how to handle payfort response on wooCommerce side while integration type is MerchantPage 2.0, which I am expecting to handle the response itself.

I need little help to understand the payfort integration process, as my search couldn't find any help online.

Thanks in advance

- I have emailed Payfort support center, but as its weekend, the response will be late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved finally, let me share the solution.

**Issue:**
In this plugin payment.php file has a function *callApi($postData, $gatewayUrl)* which is sending request to payfort to notify and parsing response to json

> $array_result = json_decode($response, true);

while the response was coming in XML format so it was returning null to $array_result.

**Solution:**
To resolve the above issue in Payfort account settings, under Account Setup > Technical Settings enable
Json for response type.

**Suggestion:**
Plugin should be updated to configured with this settings as well, if an account settings is with XML response type, then response should be parse accordingly.